# How disable login prompt when asking for featuretypes?

Tags: geoserver, authentication, workspace

Is it possible somehow disable login prompt when requesting  http://xxxxxxxx/geoserver/rest/workspaces/WORKSPACE_NAME/featuretypes.json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, REST is for messing with the GeoServer API so it is never a good idea to let unauthorised people do this.

You should probably be making a getCapabilties request to the server and getting feature types from that.

Comment: I know there is a little chance but... do you know maybe login prompt for this type of request was added at certain version of Geoserver? Because collegue of mine says that it didn't ask for login before.

Comment: No, REST API has always required a login - otherwise people could delete your layers!

Comment: I will wait for a little bit just in case someone knows a (workaround without getting into coding) way to disable login and then will mark your answer.